# MySQL conversion

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 databases A and B. There is a table called `Details` in db A wih 4 fields. The fields are `proffesional`, `amatuer`, `worldclass`, `trainee`. And I also have a table called `Details` in db B with 2 fields called `proffesional` and `trainee`.

Now what I want to achieve is to convert Table `Details` schema in db A to that of in db B. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply drop the unnecessary columns:

```
ALTER TABLE A.Details DROP COLUMN amateur;
ALTER TABLE A.Details DROP COLUMN wordclass;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE A.Details
CREATE TABLE `A.Details` SELECT * FROM `B.Details`;
```

And If you don't want to loose your data and just want to insert data from B databases's table..Go for--

```
INSERT INTO A.Details (proffesional, trainee)
SELECT *
FROM B.Details
```

Make sure amature and worlsclass are nullable..

Comment: But will I loose the 2 fields amatuer and worldclass from Details table in db A

Comment: "Now what I want to achieve is to convert Table Details schema in db A to that of in db B." isn't that your question??

Comment: Yes Rajat I need to change the schema

Comment: If you want to change he schema of A...that is you want table Details in database A to be same as one in B..then this is what above code will do

Comment: Or if you want to just insert values not change table..then don't drop just insert in the A.Details all values of B.Details

Comment: I need to keep the fields already present in table Details of db A and need to insert the contents of Table DEtails in db B to A

Comment: Is it possible Rajat ,to convert like that.

Comment: Absolutely...Just make sure primary key and nullable stuff

Comment: Run the query by putting in sql of your phpmyadmin in db A

Comment: Sorry I did not get you @Rajat

Comment: ??????????????Dude what sense did your above chat make????????????????what a great answer to regret upon

Answer (score 0):

what you want is to ALTER TABLE (DROP COLUMN):
http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/drop_column.htm